# Does the Discovery show 'Moonshiner' show the truth?

Tags: realism, moonshiner

I love Discovery channel because it's so American and most of the time there's such a drama for nothing, but I have to admit that seeing Moonshiners was some kind of a surprise.

I guess that people making alcohol illegally is something that exists pretty much everywhere, but is there any truth in the whole *trauma documentaries show* ?
Except for one episode where they all pretend not to be actors, it really seems to me that it's just a bunch of redneck actors that fake something that might indeed exist for real.

Comment: Why a downvote ? is that question bad quality or offtopic ?

Comment: The making of Home Brew is legal. You are restricted on quantity and it's not for sale. Water and Moonshine look the same, which one are we watching?

Comment: That didn't awnser the question. It mearly stated a opposition. All I can say is if I myself were engaging in illegal activities I would not agree to be filmed and put on nation wide TV. I myself find the show very entertaining And would like to think that it is real.I love watching it.Signed Deborah from Tennessee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone was doing something illegal, I would think the police would begin investigating.  Especially if it was a **series** and not just a **documentary**.

Although the guys in the show have claimed in interviews that it's legit, it has since been [determined that it isn't](http://artsbeat.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/12/30/those-dang-revenooers-virginia-agency-unhappy-with-discoverys-moonshiners/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=0).

Comment: thank you I was looking for some proof about that and you exactly bring what I need

Answer (score -2):

The camera crews and film producers would be held responsible for knowing about such an illegal operation. Same thing goes for Drugs inc,,,although the dealers wear masks the DEA would know who to question about where the dealers are operating or arrest the film makers for withholding information. Discovery channels are fools, if they think the viewers believe thier stupid programs real. It is more comedy than so called reality.
Pawn stars is a prime example of scripted nonsense. Would you hire anyone like chumly who pretends to be retarded,,,and leave him alone at night in charge of your business. No and Hell No.....The Bush people is nonsense as well,,,,no one can live in the (Bush),, with no means to support themselves. They have to many belongings to not have any money
North of the arctic circle, at least they show people trapping wild game for trading and feeding themselves which makes more sense. Some of the characters are guides for hunting which pays really well if your good at it
The story about the legend of Mick Dodge, a man walking the earth like moses, eating berries and mushrooms and salmon came clean by admitting that he is a wildlife activist and has a place to stay other than hollow tree trunks every night.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question in any way.